# SharePoint 2013 product Version miss match

Tags: 2013, version

i have question I dont know if this is a normal in SP 2013.

When I get Configuration database version is giving me `15.0.4569.1000` which is SharePoint foundation.
and near the Database server said `(Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database)`
but When I go to Upgrade and Migration > Enable Enterprise Features, the selected option is `Enterprise (Requires Enterprise client license)`.

and when I go to `Upgrade and Migration > Convert License Type` , I got license type `[SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License.]`

and all the database status is no action required.

We have multiple SharePoint farms installed in the same DB instance , 
does this make an problem ! or this is the normal behavior of SP 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Version / build numbers are same for the SharePoint Foundation as well as Server, You are on SharePoint 2013 SP1.
2. SharePoint Server build on SharePoint foundations so that's why you see foundation all over the places.
3. when you see the Enterprise features enabled or license type is EE that's mean you are on the EE license.
4. upgrade required only, if you apply some patches or hotfixs to the environment.
5. their should be no issue, if you host multiple farm database on single DB server. But it will cause performance issue if you have shared SQL Server that's way it is highly advisable to use the dedicated DBs server.

Comment: Thanks man ,,, is this the same for SharEPoint 2010 ! as far as I remember that the DB version indicates the license type